# Finding a link inside a html tag with beautifulsoup4, Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a project for my Python class and I'm pretty much stuck.
My program is getting my online anime list from my profile via web scraping.
It's supposed to fetch the title names and thumbnails and just give me the links.

My problem basically is, that I cant extract an image link inside the table row tag.

[Here is a screenshot of the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bl9f.png)

basically there is a `<tr  ..... data-title='<img src="url.jpg">` tag which contains a picture link.

It was no problem extracting the titles but it's different this time since it's inside of a tag.

```
 def Icon_Crawler(self):
    page_soup = soup(self.html_stream, "html.parser")
    elements = page_soup.findAll('tbody')

    for element in elements:
        try:
            store_rows = element.findAll("tr",attrs={"data-title"})
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    print(store_rows)
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: Instead of the screenshot, please post the actual URL for the page. That way we can test the code and see what's wrong.  Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `store_rows[0].get("data-title")`, `store_rows[1].get("data-title")`, etc. Use `for`-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would use `{"data-title": True}` instead of `attrs={"data-title"}` which doesn't work for me

Second I would use `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly and then I would use `item['data-title'] or`item.attrs['data-title']` or other method to get attribute

**EDIT:** because this attribute has HTML with tag `<img>` so I would use `BeautifulSoup` to get `src` from this tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''
<tr data-title='<img src="url1.jpg" alt="1">' >
<tr data-title='<img src="url2.jpg" alt="2">' >
'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('tr', {"data-title": True})

for item in all_items:
    print('item:', item['data-title'])
    #print('item:', item.get('data-title'))
    #print('item:', item.attrs['data-title'])
    #print('item:', item.attrs.get('data-title'))

    link = item['data-title']
    s = BS(link, 'html.parser')
    print('src:', s.find('img')['src'])
```

Result:

```
item: <img src="url1.jpg" alt="1">
src: url1.jpg
item: <img src="url2.jpg" alt="2">
src: url2.jpg
```